# Table does not have an inverse; this is an advanced setting (no object can be in multiple destinations for a specific relationship)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have three tables in my Core Data db.  EntityManagedObject, InitiativeManagedObject, ObjectiveManagedObject.  There is a 1-2-M relationship between Entity and Initiative; Entity and Objective and Entity and Entity.

I have configured the relationship to be 'to many' but I have not set an inverse relationship because I don't want an inverse relationship.  I can't have an inverse relationship anyway for initiatives and objectives the designer doesn't allow it, however it does allow it for entity to entity.

The problem is I am getting these warnings:

> EntityManagedObject.entities does not have an inverse; this is an
>   advanced setting (no object can be in multiple destinations for a
>   specific relationship)
>
> EntityManagedObject.initiatives does not have an inverse; this is an
>   advanced setting (no object can be in multiple destinations for a
>   specific relationship)
>
> EntityManagedObject.objectives does not have an inverse; this is an
>   advanced setting (no object can be in multiple destinations for a
>   specific relationship)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I was a bit confused by the inverse relationships at first but it makes sense. I know you are not supposed to think too much in terms of relational databases but in this case I find it helps me.

```
+--------+     +------------+
|        |    /|            |
| Entity |-----| Initiative |
|        |    \|            |
+--------+     +------------+
```

Looking at the diagram you would say

- An Entity has many Initiatives
- An Initiave has one Entity

So those are the two relationships you need to set up.

- Entity 'to many' Initiatives
- Initiative 'to one' Entity

Comment: I don't have the option of setting the inverse though only for entity to entity not for entity to initiative and entity to objective